# Get index of all character occurrences in a string in python using lambda expression

Tags: python-3.x

Can we get index of all characters in a string using lambda expression using Python language.

**String:** ABCDEACAAY

**Required Output:**

{A:[0, 5, 7, 8], B:[1], C:[2, 6], D:[3], E:[4], Y:[9]}

Code that I tried:

```
def getValues(c, string):
    a = []
    index = 0
    for char in string:
        if(char == c):
            a.append(index)
        index += 1
    return a

string = 'ABCDEACAAY'

items = {}

for chars in list(set(string)):
    items[chars] = getValues(chars, string)

print(items)
```

Comment: Hi Swaraj, what have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks for comment @Alexander-ReinstateMonica. I have updated the question with code that I tried.

Comment: While it could use some improvement, that seems correct. Is your issue the ordering of the output?

Comment: also, do you need to use a lambda function? because your code doesn't use them at all

Comment: I am quiet new to python and looking for improvements. @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, if the number of lines of code can be decreased, that will be very helpful.

Comment: @seven_seas, yes I am not sure if this can be converted to a one line code using lambda. I am looking forward to it, if that can be done.

Comment: I have a one line solution that does not use lambda are u interested in that?

Comment: It will work for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lambda:

```
string = 'ABCDEACAAY'
x = lambda s: {letter: [i for i, ltr in enumerate(s) if ltr == letter] for letter in s}
print(x(string))
```

As simple one line solution:

```
{letter: [i for i, ltr in enumerate(string) if ltr == letter] for letter in string}
```

Comment: This looks good. But will it iterate for same letter multiple times? like in above case, 4 times for 'A'?

Comment: yes, i think it will, you could get rid of that by using a set instead of the string
`{letter: [i for i, ltr in enumerate(string) if ltr == letter] for letter in set(string)}`

Comment: @seven_seas But then you lose ordering, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: yes. So, can we have both. Do not loose order and also iterate once. And of course using lambda is the preferred way.